# Queue job not pushed in laravel v5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on queue jobs in laravel v5.4. Now I want to send an email to users through email later function. Below is my function that I am using

```
public static function singleEmailQueueJob(){
        for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++){
             $time = $i * 10; 
             $data['email'] = 'abc@gmail.com';
             $data['name'] = "Rizwan_$time";
             $data['subject'] = 'Queue Job Testing->'.$i;
             $data['verification_code'] = base64_encode($i.time());
             \Mail::later($time,'emails.password', $data, function ($m) use ($data) {
                $m->from(CommonHelper::$email_info['admin_email'],CommonHelper::$email_info['site_title']);
                $m->to($data['email'],$data['name']);
                $m->subject($data['email']);
            });
        }
        echo "Email send successfully";
    }
```

when I run this function i receive following error in exception

```
{"success":"false","message":"Only mailables may be queued."}
```

in .eve file i set

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

and in config/queue.php

```
'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
```

I don't know where is the problem in code. Please help.

Comment: Did you run these two commands in terminal 

php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate

Comment: and also run php artisan config:cache after doing changes in .env

Comment: @pdshah3690 yes I have run these both commands but still facing the same issue

Comment: is there any entry in jobs and failed_jobs table???

Comment: @pdshah3690 no i did not found any entry in above both tables event no error found in logs file

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue by using the following code

```
$date = Carbon::now()->addMinutes($time);
Queue::later($date, new EmailSending($data));
```

Now I am able to send emails in queue

Thanks to help me

Comment: after doing this code must check for entry in jobs and jobs_failed tables

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have created job 'SendVerificationEmail' and I call this job after successful registration of user like this.

```
dispatch(new SendVerificationEmail($user));
```

Do you also dispatch(your_job) in your code???

Comment: Yes I have used this method but this method not throw any exception and also put no job in queue

Comment: This code will insert record in jobs table and when you run php artisan queue:work command it will start executing your jobs. If any failure occurs it removes entry from jobs table and insert into failed_jobs table.